# Why the local mass-ratio in a complex submanifold of the Euclidean space is nonzero?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Okay, I'm not very comfortable with either complex geometry or minimal surfaces, so bear with me. I've encountered the following theorem, but I can't find a proof:

Suppose $V\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is a properly embedded complex submanifold, say of complex-dimension $k$. Here, $\mathbb{C}^n$ is equipped with the usual Euclidean metric. The theorem says that for all $p\in V$,

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\operatorname{Vol}(V\cap B(r,p))}{r^{2k}} > 0.$$

Any thoughts about why this is true, or maybe an idea for a reference? Thanks!

Comment: This should follow from the relation of the scalar curvature to volume: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature#Relation_between_volume_and_Riemannian_scalar_curvature

Comment: Ah, you're completely right @GunnarÞórMagnússon